# How obtain first/last day of an incomplete week in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, date, calendar

and thanks for reading me.

I have a little problem that is that I need to Know the first/last day of a week **in a month** and a year, so:

```
public String getFirstDayOfWeekAndMonth(int year, int month, int week){
   Calendar weekCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   weekCalendar.clear();
   weekCalendar.set( Calendar.YEAR, year );
   weekCalendar.set( Calendar.MONTH, month-1); // zero-based
   weekCalendar.set( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week );

   return... ?
}
```

For example for the next calendar:

```
Month    Week     M   T   W   T   F   S   S           FirstDay    LastDay
          1               1   2   3   4   5              1           5
          2       6   7   8   9   10  11  12             6           12
  1       3       13  14  15  16  17  18  19             13          19
          4       20  21  22  23  24  25  26             20          26
          5       27  28  29  30                         27          30

          5                       1   2   3              1           3
          6       4   5   6   7   8   9   10             4           10
  2       7       11  12  13  14  15  16  17             11          17
          8       18  19  20  21  22  23  24             18          24
          9       25  26  27  28                         25          28

          9                       1   2   3              1           3
  3       10      4   5   6   7   8   9   10             4           10
                     ...
```

I have problems with the weeks that are in 2 months (on example 5 and 9). Could you help me please?

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have develop a method that returns the first and the last day, wothin any other library:

```
private static int getFirstDayOfWeek(int year,int month,int week){
    return getFirstLastDayOfWeek(true,year,month,week);
}

private static int getLastDayOfWeek(int year,int month,int week){
    return getFirstLastDayOfWeek(false,year,month,week);
}

private static int getFirstLastDayOfWeek(boolean first, int year,int month,int week){
    int exit = 0;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
    if (!first)
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
    // 1st day of the week
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    // The month and the day of the 1st day of the week
    int theMonth = Integer.valueOf( getInstance().getStrDate(date,"MM") );

    if (theMonth!=month)
        exit = (first?1:new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, 1).getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    else
        exit = Integer.valueOf( getInstance().getStrDate(date,"d") );
    return exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the brilliant [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library for all your timing needs (which I also recommend to make a standard import in all you projects).

With that, a (not very clean, yet working) solution would be this:

```
public String getFirstDayOfWeekAndMonth(int year, int month, int week) {
    DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, firstDayOfMonth.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValueOverall(), 0, 0, 0, 1);

    // european style (MON - SUN)
    DateTime firstOfWeek = new DateTime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1).plusWeeks(week - 1).withDayOfWeek(1);
    DateTime lastOfWeek = firstOfWeek.withDayOfWeek(7);

    int firstDay;
    int lastDay;
    if(firstOfWeek.isBefore(firstDayOfMonth))
        firstDay = firstDayOfMonth.getDayOfMonth();
    else
        firstDay = firstOfWeek.getDayOfMonth();

    if(lastOfWeek.isAfter(lastDayOfMonth))
        lastDay = lastDayOfMonth.getDayOfMonth();
    else
        lastDay = lastOfWeek.getDayOfMonth();

    String returner = String.format("%d - %d", firstDay, lastDay);

    return returner;
}
```

I don't quite get why you would want to return a String from your method, but I guess you have a reason. I just assumed a format, you can of course change it if you want.

Comment: Import a library only for a function? Is it recommended?

Comment: I think this is sledge-hammer to crack a nut... Sorry :(

Comment: What is the problem with importing a library? It is 556kb in size, so I assume your objection is not disk space. Is it library clutter? I never really understood people who claimed that they did not want to use another library for 'such a simple task'. Do you prefer reinventing the wheel then? Anyway, Joda-Time is a great library that makes working with dates much easier and faster then the native Java implementation. Looking at the 'complex' date calculations you are doing, I am assuming that there are more similar tasks going on, most of which I assume can be simplified by using Joda-Time...

Comment: Imagine that I have a fly in my bedroom that I need to kill... I have 3 solutions: to use a flypaper, to use an insecticide or call to sprayers. I have only one fly. If I had a plague I will call to the sprayers ;)

Comment: Well, in the end, it is your project and your call of course. I do not know enough about your project to really give you advice on what I think you should do. I was merely suggesting using a fast and convenient library for all your date and date-time needs. However, I am glad that you found a solution within the standard JDK that fits your requirements.

Comment: however, thank you very much for the recomendation; I´ll take a look for the library :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple logical test?

For first day of the week:

```
If (resultDate.month < input.month){
     resultDate = firstDayOf(input.month);
}
```

and for the last day of the week

```
If (resultDate.month > input.month){
    resultDate = lastDayOf(input.month);
}
```

Comment: you want to know the first (or last) day of the week right? hence the resultDate.
If you get the first day of the input week and then check if it is in the right month (statements above) you can get the right date.

Only thing I'm not sure about is what happens if the resultDate is in a different year.

Comment: I´ll do it, but I was looking for another one simple way ;). Thanks.